# Way to get stringstream >> my_double under g++ to give an infinite value or NaN?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, stream, g++

I have a c++ function that takes a string input.  In the function, I use `stringstream` to extract a `double`.

Later, I check to make sure that the double is not NaN or infinity.  However, I can't come up with a test input that will make the extraction operator yield either of those values.

Here is the important part of my function. The real use is in some class factory methods.

```
double from_text(const std::string& word, bool& failed){
  double ret; failed = true;

  std::istringstream param_in(word);
  if(!(param_in >> ret)) { 
    return ret; }
  if(is_nan_or_infinity(ret)) { 
    //I want to get here
    return ret; }

  failed = false; return ret;
}
```

You may say, if you can't produce this, why bother?

I don't want to remove the if because I know that in some implementations, [like IBM's](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flegacy%2Fref%2Fistream.htm), the stream operators can produce such values.

I don't want to ignore the problem because I want to at least get 100% statement coverage in my test cases and making exceptions means I always need to check all those files manually to ensure that the only non-covered lines are my exceptions.  Manual inspection means more mistakes.  There are only five files using code like from_text right now, so its not impossible, but I'm hoping for a better way.

**Edit**

To be clear, what I want is a way to get `std::istringstream(some_magic_string) >> my_double` to output inf and nan on a test platform consisting of g++ under Ubuntu.

Thus, I want to be able to write:

```
#include "test_stuff.hpp"
#include "from_text.hpp"
///Maybe more magic goes here
bool failed;
from_text("my_special_nan_producing_input",failed)
test_assert(failed,true,"NAN producing input causes failure");
from_text("my_special_inf_producing_input",failed)
test_assert(failed,true,"Infinity producing input causes failure");
///Clean up from all the special magic
```

And have from_text execute the branch resulting from ret being NaN or inf.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is handled seems to be implementation dependent. Some will output "inf" or "NaN" on an ostringstream but treat that as an error on the way in.
I suggest you do the following:

1. Test, via ostringstream, what your implementation puts into a string.
2. See if your istringstream returns values or treats them as an error.
3. If they are treated as an error, test in your from_text method if you got "inf" or "NaN" and return the appropriate value from there.

Unfortunately, if your software runs on multiple platforms you may need platform specific code to handle each case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't quite do what I want, though I think I can see how you interpreted my question.  For the product, I'd like to use the platform's normal `stringstream`.  The spec doesn't mention a need to return `nan` and `inf` on particular inputs, my code just needs to handle the case correctly when `stringstream` _does_ return those values.  So I need to make stringstream behave differently for tests only.

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the clarification. Yes, I understand that that is what you are trying to do. I think you are misunderstanding what I am saying. Step 1 & 2  are to determine what input, if any, in your platform's `istringstream` is likely to return `inf` or `NaN`. Step 3 describes how you use this information. If your `istringstream` appears not to return `inf` or `NaN` you have the option of relying on your existing error checking, which will not all you to meet your 100% coverage goal, or providing a way to provoke the execution of the code. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: One other test you could try to provoke the return of `inf` is manually construct a string that holds a number that is outside the dynamic range of your system's `double`.

Comment: I like the idea of using a string with a very large number.  But it didn't work on my system.